# Can't "define" two databases in the same file of Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've just started learning Python and I'm slowly getting the hang of it, but I've faced a problem.

I'm trying to make a simple website with articles using Google's App Launcher SDK.

Now, everything worked fine when I followed the little guide in Google's site, but now I want to create another database:

```
class Articles(db.Model):
    title = db.TextProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

No error here. 
I then try to make a query, fetch all info and post it into a template:

```
class Articles(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        articles_query = Articles.all().order('-date')
        articles = articles_query.fetch(10)

        template_values = {'articles': articles}

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'articles.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Here I received an error:

```
line 45, in get
    articles_query = Articles.all().order('-date')
AttributeError: type object 'Articles' has no attribute 'all'
```

I basically copied the query from Google's tutorial and just change the variables, yet it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that you've defined two databases, but that you've tried to create two classes called `Articles`. Python can't keep both of them in its head at once, so once you made `class Articles(webapp.RequestHandler)`, it replaced `class Articles(db.Model)`.

`webapp.RequestHandler` doesn't have an `all()` method, and you've not defined one in the second `Articles` class. That's why you get the particular error that you do.

You should use different names for your classes.

Comment: Ohh, I feel so ashamed.. Thanks a lot, how could I make such a mistake?

Comment: Oh, easily. I do 3 things like this every day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor in this way <sup>*</sup>:

1. rename `class Articles(webapp.RequestHandler)` in `class ArticlesHandler(webapp.RequestHandler)`
2. move your `Articles` model in a separate file called `models.py`
3. add `from models import Articles` to your *webhandlers* file

Have a Handler suffix help you to distinguish canonical classes from Web handlers;
a different `models.py` module isolates your model implementations in one place and could be useful when your project will become more complex.

<sup>* step 1 is enough for resolving your specific issue</sup>